# HTTP Server Status 404 Error in Spring MVC Project

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller

**I am following the same tutuorial as in this [404 Error - Java Spring MVC using Maven in Eclipse from Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229472/404-error-java-spring-mvc-using-maven-in-eclipse-from-tutorial)  and after filling the form i am getting 404 Error**

> index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="add">
    <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="t2"><br>
    <input type="submit">   
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> web.xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <servlet>          
    <servlet-name>telusko</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    
  </servlet>
 
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>telusko</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

> AddController.java

```
package com.telusko;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class AddController {
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add() {
        return "display.jsp";
    }
}
```

> telusko-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">
    
    
    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.telusko"></ctx:component-scan>
</beans>
```

> display.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

**Source Project**

[image]

So how can i succesfully get the "display.jsp" page after filling the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It Helps Me**

> I have just created few changes and i succesfully remove the HTTP 404
>   Error even after adding RequestMapping Annotation
>
> I have just move my packageand classes into the src/main/java and not
>   into the src/main/resources which i have to created manually,  and
>   that should resolve the Mapping error.

**New Project Structure**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing InternalResourceViewResolver bean in your telusko-servlet.xml

```
<!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Also its good practice to put your jsp pages in WEB-INF/view folder not outside of it.
After adding that bean you do not return
 display.jsp

Your controller method should look like

```
@RequestMapping("/add")
public String add() {
    return "display";
}
```

Also it would be wise to avoid versions in your bean xml, if above does not help try using something like

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call "/addController/add" like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/addController ")
public class AddController {
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add() {
        return "display";
    }
}
```

Comment: you can call "/addController/add" like this